# Gravity of listview items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I am trying to recreate the way the `views` are laid out in a chat application (with messages from me aligned to the right and other messages aligned to the left). As of now, I am using a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`.

Initially, each list item was a `textview`, but `AbsListView.LayoutParams` does not have  gravity. Therefore, I wrapped up my textviews in a `LinearLayout` and then set the gravity of the textview dynamically by getting it `LayoutParams` and casting that to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. I thought this would work, but alas it didn't!!

I searched for the reason behind it and I did come across some posts which say that I need another `LinearLayout` inside my first `LinearLayout` for the gravity values to be honored or use a `RelativeLayout` with `layout_alignEnd` or `layout_alignStart` to achieve the effect.

It would be great if someone can explain as to why the layout with a single `LinearLayout` doesn't honor the gravity values

Comment: I think you have to define two layout in ur list item layout set their gravity as you wan to show...

Comment: @Haresh - Yes, I am aware of that, but I would like to know as to why it can't be accomplished just by using a single `LinearLayout` parent